# obtain values of column by name from another columns and add more columns with na

Tags: r, data.table

Before, my question was how to get column values by name from other columns that include na?, but now this table is dynamic, if there are more columns (maximum 6 columns), it should be the columns with value and the rest in NA.

That is, if there are 2 with name and value put var1 and value_v1, var2 and value_v2, there should be var3 and value3 = NA until you get var6 and value6

Here is a simple example.

```
 THis table is dinyamic, there may be more columns or not.  

 > d
     value1   value2      var1 
1:     one     two     value1
2:     uno     dos     value2
3:       1       2     value1
4:      NA      NA      NA
5:       6       7     value2
```

I have a solution to add a column (value of column=value_v1,value_v2...etc) which contains the value of the column specified by '(name of column= var1, var2..)

I have the solution is for this case:

d[, value_v1 := get(replace(var1, is.na(var1), "value1")), 1:nrow(d)]
d[, value_v2 := get(replace(var2, is.na(var2), "value2")), 1:nrow(d)]

```
> d
```

But I need considering if there exists more name of column and value of column (up to 6).
This could be the result, in case there was another columana, the idea is to get to var6

```
> d
   value1    value2         var1    value_v1   var2    value_v2
1:     one     two         value1    one        na       na
2:     uno     dos         value2    dos        na       na
3:       1       2         value1    1          na       na 
4:      NA       NA          NA      NA         na       na
5:      6        7         value2    7          na       na
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be `get`

```
d[, value.of.col := get(replace(name.of.col, is.na(name.of.col), 
                "value.1")), 1:nrow(d)]
d
#   value.1 value.2 name.of.col value.of.col
#1:     one     two     value.1          one
#2:     uno     dos     value.2          dos
#3:       1       2     value.1            1
#4:    <NA>    <NA>        <NA>         <NA>
#5:       6       7     value.2            7
```

---

Or using `row/col` indexing from `base R`

```
i1 <- !is.na(d$name.of.col)
m1 <- cbind(seq_len(nrow(d[i1,])), match(d$name.of.col[i1], names(d)))
d$value.of.col[i1] <- as.data.frame(d)[i1, 1:2][m1]
```

Comment: @Lectxx7  in which case?  Sorry didn't get your question